# Git "workflow" and branches in a website project

Tags: git, version-control, web, workflow, vs-web-site-project

I know the basics of Git and can run it for my own purposes. However, the concept of how to make the most of it is a bit vague for me.

Now that I've been using it for a day or two I've been trying figure it out to myself.
Perhaps in a website project (lets presume Drupal) there could be branches for:

- themes
- modules
- libraries (perhaps)
- master (of course)
- and perhaps something for testing?

This way I could understand that for example a themer could work with own "theme" branch that is eventually merged into master.
Or am I totally lost with this?

What I'm looking for is concrete examples to understand the workflow?
How to make use of Git?

Comment: Why do you think you need branches at all? Are you working with other people? Managing new features that take a long time to develop while maintaining a release line? Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve with branches? Note that the idea of having separate *parts* of the project in separate branches is absolutely not what they're for.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manage themes, modules, libraries etc separately, you can develop them in different branches and then merge into master branch after finishing development each time.

You find refer  [basic branching](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) and [branching workflows](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows) in git book for detail examples and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow you choose really depends on what you need to get out of Git.

In my experience with Drupal, I've found it more helpful to make [feature branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows#feature-branch-workflow). The workflow is simple: when you start working on a new feature, you start a new branch for it. When the feature is done, you merge it into master. (This workflow pairs really nicely with Pull Requests. It's helpful when collaborating with other people.)

For example: Let's say you want to build a complex, feature-rich image gallery in your Drupal site. It's likely that you'll need to..

- ..install a module or two, maybe even a library.
- ..make changes to your theme.
- ..and implement tests to make sure this feature is well built.

If you use the branches you've suggested, you'd have to do this work across *all* of them. This would be difficult, to say the least. If you install your modules and build out the basic gallery in one branch, why would you switch to another branch in order to theme it?

Not to mention, it'd get messy quickly: if you're working on other features at the same time, and/or with other developers, your commits for this feature will be immediately mixed in with all the other work, and it'll be hard to keep track of your progress on each feature.

Instead of splitting that work over many branches, I'd just start a new branch called "gallery", complete my work there, and merge it into master when it's ready. Work for each feature stays isolated in its own branch till it's totally done.